# Zener diode as voltage limiter in a voltage divider?

Tags: voltage-divider, zener

Can I use a Zener diode to limit the output voltage of a voltage divider?

I made a simple voltage divider (shown in the figure) that with 5V input gives me an output voltage of 3.3V. I Want to use this as a voltage sensor (0-3.3V in the ADC of microcontroller.)

I tried to implement a 3.3V Zener diode to limit the voltage when it goes above 3.3V (in case of the input voltage goes above 5V for any reason) but it did not go as expected. Even when the output voltage is below 3.3V, when I insert the Zener diode it lowers the output voltage. When I get, for example, 2.5V in the output, if I insert the zener diode it drops to 2V.

Is there any way to make the Zener diode just limit voltages above the 3.3V?

[image]

Comment: Reducing R1 to 1k should help. Use 3v6 zener to move the clamp level little higher (out of 0-3v3 range).

Comment: Taigo, is protection of the input pin the reason you want a sharp cutoff? What's the "sensor" supposed to do for you? Are you measuring with an ADC to detect the presence or absence of something? Or do you need to carefully observe a wide detailed range of voltages for some more complex reasons?

Comment: I want to read the voltage with a microcontroller, and if the voltage goes above 3,3v it can damage the microcontroller, thats why i want to limit it.

Comment: I need to carefully observe a wide detailed range of voltages, use this sensor as a voltmeter. The 0-5v range is just an example, in fact i want 0-50v input range (r1 and r2 will have different values), and due to the fact that i have discharged capacitor (at the very beginning) in the circuit, in the first miliseconds the capacitor works as a short-circuit and the voltage raises more than 50v for this short period of time, so thats why i want to protect this overvoltages so that the microcontroller ADC pin don't burn.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you *can*, but it will not work well. That's because a 3.3 V Zener diode has a very "soft knee". That is, it conducts some current well below 3.3 V, and it doesn't conduct much current above 3.3 V.

[image]

If you want a sharp transition at 3.3 V, you need to use an IC: a shunt voltage reference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM1FD6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The next best thing is a Schottky diode that goes to a 2.9 V reference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFpL0m.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: So, i read the datasheet of lm3411m5 and it seems to be a 3.3V regulator, which is not what i pretend. How can it work as a voltage limiter?

Comment: That's exactly what a shunt regulator does: if the voltage is 3.299 V, it shunts almost no current; if the voltage is 3.001 V, it shunts as much current as it can; if the voltage is exactly 3.000 V, it shunts just a little bit of current, just enough to keep the voltage at 3.000 V.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I think you're overstating the precision of the LM3411. It's good, but it's not that good.

Answer (score 4):

Let’s suppose that you are not using any Zener diode and that you want to measure a voltage from 0 to 5V, for a maximum limited input of 3.3V, which is what you microcontroller can accept.

For that you have built a voltage divider that allows for a straight line conversion of 0-5V to 0-3.3V like the chart below.

[image]

However, it is very difficult to find a Zener diode that can limit your maximum voltage for values below 5V and at the same time give you a straight line in you voltage divider, like you have found out.

But how about if you could limit your maximum voltage below the critical value of 3.3V and still be able to have a straight line to work with?

How about the circuit below? From 0 to 3V (x axis) in the input you have 0 to 1V (blue line) output in a straight line. This is because the transistors will not be conducting as per red line.

[image]

What it is interesting is that you can even feed 0 to 50V and still have the same limits as per chart below.

[image]

Look closely.

[image]

You just have to have the right relationship in the code on your microcontroller to translate from 0 to 1V to 0 to 3V. When you read 0.5 volts it means an input voltage of 1.5V.
Here are the various values in a table format:

I marked some spots where the line starts not to be as straight, but it is still close enough.

[image]

Here is the formula for calculating Range:

[image]

So the maximum Range will be (R1 values in Kilo ohms):

[image]

Here it is for a range of 0 to 10V:

[image]

Your code in the microcontroller needs to mark any value that when read is translated to a value above 1 volt as having reached the maximum and the user has to change the R1 resistor value as per Range formula.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to restrict voltage levels at an IC input so as to not exceed its power rails (by a dangerous amount) is to put Schottky diodes to the rails:

[image]

The Schottky diodes only turn on when signal exceeds the rail by 0.2 or 0.3V which is a small enough excursion beyond the rails to not harm the connected IC.

If your input signal source is not capable of generating negative voltages then you don't need the second diode to ground.

Comment: but when SIGNAL is above 12V the 3.3V reference will slowly increase and will eventually exceeds the max limit (4V) when SIGNAl is around 20V.

Comment: This circuit does assume 3.3V comes from a solid voltage source and won't "slowly increase" for mysterious reasons. If it is weak (high output impedance) then it is not a useful solution.

Comment: I tried it once with 3.3V source from a LDO and it does just that, so I don't know what happened and the LTspice sim can't output the same result, which is quite mysterious.

Comment: An LDO is only really designed to source current and we're asking it to sink current here. If the net current from 3.3V becomes negative (sink) then I suspect you'll have this problem. Maybe forcing the LDO to source more current (add dummy load) will keep it in its active region and keep the 3.3V rail stable.